# Transpose data by checking similar cell data

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, transpose

I have a Excel sheet like below..

```
Color   Size    Qty
Red     L       182
Red     M       223
Red     S       155
Red     XS      30
Blue    L       700
Blue    M       845
Blue    S       665
Blue    XS      357
Green   L       173
Green   M       200
Green   S        67
Green   XS       34
```

But I need to convert that sheet as per below...

```
        L   M   S   XS
Red     182 223 155 30
Blue    700 845 665 357
Green   173 200 67  34
```

Comment: Did you try using Pivot tables?

Answer (score 0):

Either a pivot table or copy - paste special - transpose